# What databse is most similar to Map, where there are stored infinity "keys" and "values" per individual user/id?

Tags: java, sql, database, storage

I want to create user database for my application. It sounds simple but I do not know which database will be the best for this.

I want to let user set his own variables like "points = 5". He will have posibility to expand his indexes keys and values as much as he will want. All his data must be linked to his name.

Something like:

```
Josh -> "points":"5"
        "health":"20"
        ...
        "indexN":"valueN"

Joel -> "food":"5"
        "feels":"good"

...  ->  ...
```

This database will be read from multiple servers so it can not be local like JSON, CSV, YAML or SQLite. The good solution is MySQL but structure of this database requires to create tables and columns inside of tables for individual type of row names:values.

It can be also stored like this in mysql with only 2 columns (`Name`, `Value`), and values may look like this:

```
1: "Joel", "'food':'5', 'feels':'good', "
2: "Josh", "'points':'5', 'health':'4', "
```

But is there any better way than stoarging data per user like this? Is there any database dedicated for needs like mine?

Comment: [Bigtable: A Distributed Storage System for Structured Data](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf)

Comment: Is there any open source database like this? I have my own dedicated servers and I want to use only them.

Comment: Yes. See [Apache Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/).

Comment: redis hashes will do exactly what you want. hset and hget example here: https://redis.io/commands/hget and https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro (look for hash example which describes your use case of a user's attributes)

Comment: Ask on the sister site, Software Recommendations Stack Exchange. List very specifically your criteria for choosing a database, and Answers appear to suggest a specific solution.

Comment: Do redis server save all set data after disabling it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a database like MySQL using 2 tables.  The 2 tables schema would be something like this:

```
Table1
id

Table2
id
key
value
```

And populated with your data, it would look something like this:

```
Table1
id=Josh
id=Joel

Table2
id=Josh,key=points,value=5
id=Josh,key=health,value=20
id=Joel,key=points,value=5
```

This allows you to add a dynamic amount of key value pairs for the ids in Table1.  This might not be the ideal solution, just one that would work in MySQL or other relational databases.

Comment: For what table1 is need if table2 also has id? Also I do not want to put multiple records with same id. I want ID to be individual to select all the data with just one query or request.

Comment: I assumed you would have more columns within Table1 that you didn't list, such as other user information.  If that is literally all the data you need, then you would only need Table2.  However, if there are keys that appear for all your users, I would put it in Table1 and only put keys in Table2 that are dynamically created.